# Hibernate envers: maven dependency version information

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-envers

Do I have to include version information in the pom.xml like below?
I just want to add envers - already included hibernate-core without version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.Final</version> <!--this one-->
</dependency>
```

When I exclude version info,  there is no valid jar file in my .m2 directory.

Just created unknown folder and unknown file inside it.

I already have 5.2.9.Final hibernate-core, but I just wonder I have to write down version number in my hibernate-envers dependency.

Comment: See related Question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29476680/3656963

Comment: thanks it helped @Revive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what is influencing the `hibernate-core` dependency's version.  Is that coming from some parent pom or dependency management section?

My first suggestion is to determine what influences `hibernate-core`.  Once you know that, you should be able to make it influence `hibernate-envers`.

That aside, I generally define a set of properties like:

```
<properties>
  <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

And then for each of my hibernate artifacts, I reuse that version so that the appropriately versioned bundles are used and I don't need to maintain updating that version information in multiple places.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```