# jar is missing in pom.xml error but is usually not included

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a really basic program in spring. This is a snippet of my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is the error I am getting:

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar is missing.
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar is missing.
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar is missing.

I get that this is because my dependencies don't have a < version > section. However, in all the other java applications that I have worked on, including the one I am referencing right now, the versions for these basic dependencies are never included. Is there something else in my pom that I am supposed to include beforehand, that may be included in the files that I am referencing but not the one I have created from scratch? If not, how are they working without the version included in their pom dependencies?
Additionally, how would I go about finding the version for these basic dependencies?

Comment: In short, something within your project must declare your dependency versions. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476472/maven-dependency-without-version for some similar answers. To your additional question, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test.

Answer (score 1):

Please add Spring Starter Web Maven Dependency in Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As Spring downloads latest version of dependency so we do not have to declare explcitly.